Confusion around 3-wire/4-wire three phase voltage sensing
I'm trying to understand the voltage sensing setup when measuring three phase voltages in a 3 wire system (like Delta with no neutral) or a 4 wire system (like WYE) or Delta High leg (delta with neutral). I'd like to see a circuit that is capable of both.
I have seen cases like below where it is expecting a physical neutral connection (no connected to ground). The image has been simplified for ilustration purposes. In this case the amplifier is going to sense the Phase to Neutral voltage. Now, what happens to this setup in a 3-wire system with no neutral? The neutral connection is left floating which doesn't look like a good idea.

Then I have seen circuits where the phase voltage is sensed with respect to the board ground. Or the neutral is tied to ground. In other cases, I have seen the neutral being measured in a separate ADC channel.

So my question is, what is the right circuit to measure phase voltage accurately when you have a neutral or don't have a neutral at all? When you have a neutral, one cannot always assume it will be ground or 0V.

What's wrong with faking a neutral for your 3 wire delta?

How would I fake a neutral?
